# SQL query compare both date and time mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, compare

I want to compare dates and times but the code below only compares dates

tbl_table

```
id               date_start                    date_end
1          2020-04-20 09:06:00             2020-04-21 09:06:00
2          2020-04-21 08:45:00             2020-04-25 09:45:00
3          2020-04-21 09:00:24             2020-04-21 04:00:24
```

When I run code below:

```
SELECT * FORM tbl_table
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN date_start AND date_end
```

```
id               date_start                    date_end
1          2020-04-20 09:06:00             2020-04-21 09:06:00
```

The time I run this code at : `2020-04-21 11:00:00`

The above code compares only by date. Any help much appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: What are your time variables? If `date_start` and `date_end` are `datetime` or `timestamp` you are already comparing dates and times.

Comment: @Nick My time variables are `timestamp` . But it only compares by date

Comment: It is comparing times as well e.g. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wrTvugaKF8ofhG6wSRGJnA/0 If you're not seeing that behaviour you need to create a [mcve] for debugging